# How to securely upload a file (csv) file through an iPhone app into a secure storage space? (xcode, secure)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, csv, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Thanks for reading this.

I've been searching for an easy way to upload a csv file generated in the users iPhone app to a secure storage drive.

For a research project, we are looking to ask participants to answer a couple of questions that will be compiled into a csv file. 
All those files need to be uploaded anonymised to one secure storage location for further processing of the results.

I have looked into Google Drive (didn't work for iOS), Softlayer Object Storage but there doesn't seem to be an easy out of the box solution. 
I have been jumping through customer support for two weeks.

In an ideal world:
CSV file created in the iPhone app
User agrees to share the file
CSV file uploaded through the iPhone app into a secure storage

Ideal solution:
HIIPA complaint or secure solution 
ready wrappers for implementing in xCode
Half a day of work max

Thanks again,

Best,
Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally settled of Google Firebase iOS SDK. The Firebase Storage function is fantastic. 
It was very easy to integrate and the support was excellent. 
We used a file upload function to the firebase storage.

Highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you:

http://blog.softlayer.com/2014/softlayer-security-questions-and-answers

"5: How is my data kept private? How can I confirm that SoftLayer can’t read my confidential data?
A: This question is common customers who deal with sensitive workloads such as HIPAA-protected documentation, employee records, case files, and so on.

SoftLayer customers are encouraged to deploy a gateway device (e.g. Vyatta appliance) on which they can configure encryption protocols. Because the gateway device is the first hop into SoftLayer’s network, it provides an encrypted tunnel to traverse the VLANs that reside on SoftLayer. When securing compute and storage resources, customers can deploy single tenant dedicated storage devices to establish isolated workloads, and they can even encrypt their hard drives from the OS level to protect data at rest. Encrypting the hard drive helps safeguard data even if SoftLayer were to replace a drive or something similar."

It seems that you will need to create your server to store your data and deploy a gateway device as well.

In another hand about object storage I did not find any information if it supports HIIPA, but as the softlayer object storage is based on Open Stack I think that if Open Stack supports HIIPA Softlayer's object storage should support it as well. Just in case here some documentation about how to work with object storage using REST:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

Regards